# Powershell -how to remove line details from selectstring output

Tags: powershell

I want to select a string "install status" from a log file by using powershell. For that i have used the command $status=selectstring -path $path -pattern "installstatus" .This cmd given an output installstatus=success with path and logtime and line details at beginning and i removed the path by adding |{$_.Line} after pattern in $status.And i want to remove line details also.how can i remove those details.I only want the pattern to be displayed .Any help will be apperciated.Thanks in advancd.

here the scenarios

```
$path="C:\Users\sumith\filename.log";
$status=select-string -path $path -pattern "Install_status"
```

output is

```
C:\Users\sumith\filename.log:79:ISS_LOG [14:45:41]: INSTALL_STATUS:SUCCESS
```

if i give

```
$status=select-string -path $path -pattern "Install_status" | {$_.Line}
```

the output will be

```
ISS_LOG [14:45:41]: INSTALL_STATUS:SUCCESS
```

now i want to remove `ISS_LOG [14:45:41]:` from output

Comment: Please paste your output ,so that we can help you tweak the code to get the required output.

Comment: `$path="C:\Users\sumith\filename.log";`
`$status=select-string -path $path -pattern "Install_status"` ,output is **C:\Users\sumith\filename.log:79:ISS_LOG [14:45:41]: INSTALL_STATUS:SUCCESS**  if i give `$status=select-string -path $path -pattern "Install_status" | {$_.Line}` the output will be  **ISS_LOG [14:45:41]: INSTALL_STATUS:SUCCESS**    now i want remove ISS_LOG [14:45:41]: from output @ChetanKulkarni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$status=select-string -path $path -pattern "Install_status" | {$_.Line}
$status.Substring(19)OR

 $status=select-string -path $path -pattern "Install_status" | {$_.Line}
$status.Substring($status.IndexOf('IN'))

or

 $status=select-string -path $path -pattern "Install_status" | {$_.Line}
 $status.Substring($status.IndexOf(']:')+2)


    Or using Regex (Credits to LotPengs)
 $Content=Get-Content D:\creditdetails.txt
$Pattern = [regex]'INSTALL_STATUS:\s*(\w+)'
if( $Pattern.Matches($Content) -ne $null){
$Matches=$Pattern.Matches($Content)
$Matches.Captures[0].Value 
}else{
$Matches='No Match Found'
}
```

Assuming the log structure remains the same.

Comment: is there any way to get output without hard coding ?

Comment: There are plenty ways,provided  log structure remains the same,If possible let us know how the log looks like.

Comment: This a part of log file and you can see the install status at the end 
      'ISS_LOG [14:45:41]: ======================================================================================================================================================
ISS_LOG [14:45:41]: Event: OnSumithSetupEnd
ISS_LOG [14:45:41]: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{A13B05B8-C7C2-4275-9B52-5BDE7142655F} Does not exist.
ISS_LOG [14:45:41]: ISD Version:  and Registry Display Version : 
ISS_LOG [14:45:41]: INSTALL_STATUS: SUCCESS`

Comment: Looking at these logs,I can say that at every new line of log you have ISS_LOG[XX:XX:XX]:,These are fixed,Hence hardcoding can be the best solution.As the first 19 characters are useless.

Comment: $status.Substring(19)   this will give the exact output what i'm looking for ,thanks for that, but the problem is about hardcoding.I hope u can help me to avoid the hardcoding also

Comment: ` $status.Substring($status.IndexOf(']:')+2)` this one also giving the ,but here also hardcoding,right? If there is no way to avoid hardcoding we can go with your answer .

Comment: $status.Substring($status.IndexOf('IN'))

Comment: I cant say its hardcoding now,If this helps,Upvote the answer.Cheers

Comment: Brother one more help .ist possible to get the same out through regex ?

Comment: $Content=Get-Content filename                                                             $Pattern = [regex]'INSTALL_STATUS:\s*(\w+)'
$Matches = $Pattern.Matches($Content)
$Matches.Captures[0].Value
$Matches.Captures.Groups[1].Value

Comment: for me its giving an error "cannot index to a null array"

Answer (score 1):

IMO you are better of using a regular expression for this:

```
$File = ".\filename.log"
$Content = (Get-Content $File -raw)

$Pattern = [regex]'INSTALL_STATUS:\s*(\w+)'

"Using -Match operator"
if ($Content -Match $Pattern){
   $Matches[0]
   $Matches[1]
} Else {
  "couldn#T find a match"
}

"Using [RegEx] .Matches method"

$Matches = $Pattern.Matches($Content)

$Matches.Captures[0].Value
$Matches.Captures.Groups[1].Value
```

Your question and comment differ in the file content,
a space following the colon `INSTALL_STATUS: SUCCESS`.

Sample output :

```
Using -Match operator
INSTALL_STATUS: SUCCESS
SUCCESS
Using [RegEx] .Matches method
INSTALL_STATUS: SUCCESS
SUCCESS
```

Comment: `$Matches = $Pattern.Matches($Content)` from here i will get the output with  additional details that i dont want .when i give `$Matches.Captures[0].Value` this input it showing the error cannot index to a null array,i have tried with some other index values but showing the same error

Comment: yes it has given installed status and some other values also about the line

Answer (score 0):

For console output (modified Chetan Kulkarni answer)

(Select-String -Path .\file.txt -Pattern 'abcde').line